# calling a function more then once on change event in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in a drawing app, and I have a conflict i can't seem to fix: 
when drawing a polygon, you must first choose num of edges in a select input. then click twice for the center and radius points on the polygon (black polygon in the picture)
The problem is if you now change the num of edge and try to draw a new polygon, 2 polygons appear on top of each other (blue polygons).

my function looks something like:

```
function MyPoly(){
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
//on change - get n: number of edges
var selection = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var n = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;

$(".canvas").on("click", function( $event ){    
//some code for drawing a polygon..
});
});
```

and this is the result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I call the same function with different values on change event without getting it to run both ?

Comment: Why are you adding multiple event handlers for "click" in the "change" handler? Only rarely would you need to add an event handler inside another handler.

Comment: because I first want to detect when the number of edges changes, and then wait for the user to click. what would you suggest to avoid it?

Comment: The click event is distinct, though; it's not directly related to the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing multiple events fire because on("click") does NOT override the previous, so on every change you are adding another event to the click.

Either bind the event outside of the change (what most people would do) OR unbind the event before you reassign it.

```
$(".canvas").off("click").on("click" ...
```

Comment: thank you , thats working . I never used bind, guess I should read more about it